# Straightforward way to get product of a dict keys with its values

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, product, python-itertools

I have this dictionary for grouping filenames and extensions:

```
email_fields = {'txt': ('subject', 'plaintext_body'),
                'html': ('html_body',)}
```

I need to get a list of tuples like this:

```
>>> get_my_list(email_fields)
[('txt', 'subject'), ('txt', 'plaintext_body'), ('html', 'html_body')]
```

I would like to use something like `starmap`, `product` and `chain` from `itertools` module to do it:

```
foo = starmap(product, email_fields.items())
chain.from_iterable(foo)
```

The problem I have is that `product` takes two iterables and, as `email_fields`'s keys are strings, I get something like this:

```
[('t', 'subject'),
 ('t', 'plaintext_body'),
 ('x', 'subject'),
 ('x', 'plaintext_body'),
 ('t', 'subject'),
 ('t', 'plaintext_body')],
 ('h', 'html_body'),
 ('t', 'html_body'),
 ('m', 'html_body'),
 ('l', 'html_body')]
```

Is there a better way to do it? The closest I got works, but looks uglier:

```
foo = [product([ext], field) for ext, field in email_fields.items()]
chain.from_iterable(foo)
```

Comment: I guess that is subjective... :)

Comment: I think your solution is good enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do, manually iterating over the keys and then the values for each key:

```
[(k, v) for k in email_fields for v in email_fields[k]]
```

**Output:**

```
[('txt', 'subject'), ('txt', 'plaintext_body'), ('html', 'html_body')]
```

No need for `itertools` here. :)

Comment: But I want my `itertools` back! :)

Comment: i think this producing wrong results for second loop if v remove comma in second key ie html_body

Comment: @hso Lol, I don't have a clue what I'm doing with `itertools`. If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it after the grace period has passed? You can do it by clicking on the tick below the vote counts so it turns green. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexThornton no problem, I was just joking. I'm just toying with `itertools` and thought a "starmap product chain" sounded kinda awesome :P

Comment: `itertools` is a great library, I've been trying to learn it myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without `product` itself, by simply iterating the dictionary and then each and every value, like this

```
print [(k, item) for k in email_fields for item in email_fields[k]]
# [('txt', 'subject'), ('txt', 'plaintext_body'), ('html', 'html_body')]
```